# Too broad flag disputed, how should this be flagged?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I came across the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817268/wicket-link-to-page-inside-text):

> i would like to have link to a wicket page embedded in text (placed in .properties file). Is something like that possible or i need to create custom solution?
>
> Thx

I flagged this as being too broad, but it got disputed. How should I have flagged this? Or am i mistaken and is this actually a good quality question?

Comment: Looks too broad to me; how about you link the question so it can be closed?

Comment: @Daedalus was hoping to minimize the meta effect but it's allready generating downvotes. Link added.

Comment: Seems more unclear than broad (especially based on the comment there), but I also know nothing about Wicket.

Comment: @timo If you paste the question text here, we can just google for it, might as well include the link then ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns That still requires an extra action. Hence the "minimize" meta effect in stead of "Nullify" =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flag was disputed because 3 others thought the question looked okay when they [reviewed it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9655503).

As fas as having disputed flags goes [Quoting from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511):

> While having declined flags is bad, having disputed flags is...less so. They're certainly not something to be as concerned about, because it usually means someone wasn't specifically evaluating your flag, but rather performing some related action that rendered your flag "moot" in some way.

Since the question is now closed I would have to say you initial reaction was correct and you were just unlucky in the triage queue.  Once you gain the [close and reopen privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) your close vote will stick on the question as it is no longer a flag and you will not get a disputed flag if 3 other people vote looks okay.